# What should your calendar be AFTER you get done with Rushfit?

Tags: nutrition, weight-loss, cardio

We made it all the way through Rushfit advanced calendar. Now where do we go? 
We would like to stay with the same workouts that are on the calendar.

Should we start over at the last 2 months, 1 month? Create a whole new calendar based on the last month?

What have all of you done after completing it? We just want to stay at the same or a little higher intensity that the calendar gave us, and stay in shape.

Comment: Any reason you need to stick to Rushfit? If you prefer a program and Rushfit doesn't offer one, why not pick something else? It would help if you stated your goal more clearly, is there something lacking from simply repeating all the workouts?

Answer (score 1):

I would blend it with another program, although Rushfit is my personal favorite.   I'd workout my own well-thought out blend w/p90x, p90x2 and RushFit, and/or other programs.

Personally I got [RushFit here](http://gsprushfit-mmareview.com/), and looks like they offer some [extra bonus's](http://gsprushfit-mmareview.com/).